# Codeigniter App on EC2 - Helpers not loading

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ec2, lamp

I recently just started to migrate over a CI application to Amazon's EC2 service.  To test I set up a micro instance of ubuntu and a LAMP stack.  PHP, MySQL, HTTPD are all working beautifully.  The one issue i'm having now is that when I run my application I receive an error saying that my helpers won't load.  The helpers in particular that aren't loading are the ones in subdirectories in the helpers directory ie: /var/www/system/application/helpers/subdirectory/foo_helper.php

The helpers are being autoloaded and in my autoload.php config file they are written like:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('subdirectory/foo', 'foo2',...);
```

Has anyone run into this issue, or have any pointers on where I could go look in my configuration to resolve this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try debugging the `helper` function of the `Loader` class, in particular these lines :

**system/libraries/Loader.php**

```
elseif (file_exists(APPPATH.'helpers/'.$helper.EXT))
{ 
    include_once(APPPATH.'helpers/'.$helper.EXT);
}
```

This is the code that will be hit when including application helpers. Check what path CodeIgniter is trying to include. Double check that the path exists - everyone makes typos now and again ;-)

Comment: Just to add to Stephen's answer, a good way to check whether Loader is looking at the right path for your helper would be to add an echo APPPATH.'helpers/'.$helper.EXT before the IF loop and see what it outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The paths all seem to be right, the application was working on my windows dev server before I moved it to EC2.  So misspellings aren't an issue or they would have shown up on the development.  

Another really weird thing I have noticed with EC2 is whenever I get a php execution error.  I will go in and fix the mistake and then when I refresh I still get the same error.  Its like EC2 has the code cached or something.  Its really frustrating to debug like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that when I moved from Windows to Linux I forgot to take into account that linux is case-sensitive.  So now I need to go through and rename my files and folders.

But this still doesn't solve the issue where it seems like the page is being cached and I'm not able to refresh and see my changes.  Is there any way to force the page to grab a fresh copy from the server on every refresh?